# Select element whereby its name equals value of an attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an input XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Rules>
        <Rule ruleName="Rule1" ruleType="A"/>
        <Rule ruleName="Rule2" ruleType="B"/>
        <Rule ruleName="Rule3" ruleType="C"/>
    </Rules>
    <Description>
        <Rule1>My description for rule 1</Rule1>
        <Rule2>My description for rule 2</Rule2>
        <Rule3>My description for rule 3</Rule3>
    </Description>
</Root>
```

I need to transform it by means of XSLT into a structure as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Rules>
        <Rule ruleName="Rule1" ruleType="A"/>
            <Description>My description for rule 1</Description>
        </Rule>
        <Rule ruleName="Rule2" ruleType="B"/>         
            <Description>My description for rule 2</Description>
        </Rule>
        <Rule ruleName="Rule3" ruleType="C">
            <Description>My description for rule 3</Description>
        </Rule>
    </Rules>
</Root>
```

It means that for each */Root/Rules/Rule* node I have to select the value from the corresponding */Root/Description/Rule?* node based on the */Root/Rules/Rule/@ruleName* value. The order of */Root/Rules/Rule* and */Root/Description/Rule?* is random.

I have created a template to process the */Root/Rules/Rule* nodes but I cannot work out how to compose an xpath as **"select the node value from */Root/Description* where the node name equals *./@ruleName*"**. Any idea or procedure how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a key with `name="ref" match="Description/*" use="local-name()"`, then you can use `key('ref', @ruleName)` to find the Description element. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key.

As an alternative, you can use `current()` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current) to write XPath expressions relative to the currently matched node, i.e. if you use

```
<xsl:template match="/Root/Rules/Rule">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <Description>
         <xsl:value-of select="/Root/Description/*[local-name() = current()/@ruleName]"/>
      </Description>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

you get the same result as with the key. Consider to read up on keys however, it is a fundamental concept in XSLT to efficiently follow cross-references.

Answer (score 2):

Though I like Martin's solution with keys more, see the following solution storing the rule name in a variable and using it then in an XPath expression:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select = "Root/Rules/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rule">
 <xsl:variable name="rulename" select="@ruleName"/>
   <xsl:element name="Rule">
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     <xsl:element name="Description">
       <xsl:copy-of select="/Root/Description/*[local-name() = $rulename]/text()"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```